# Brakes are suddenly hard to push since I put new pads on, why?

Tags: brakes, chrysler, van

I recently put new front brake pads on my wife's 2010 Chrysler Town and Country. I did not change the rotors as they were new last time I changed the pads and they still felt smooth and thick enough. Immediately after putting the new pads on the brakes are hard to press. They will stop but they do not stop as quick as they used to and the pedal is giving a lot more resistance than it used to. I don't think it is the vacuum considering the change happened immediately after changing the pads. Could I have done something when I changed the pads that would have caused this??

Comment: Let the pads wear in and don't brake fiercely to test them.

Comment: Would that affect how hard the pedal is to push? I don't recall ever having the brakes be hard to press after putting new pads on in the past. Even when not braking fiercely, the pedal is much harder to push than it used to be.

Comment: Perhaps it feels hard, because it needs more effort to acheive the same stopping power (until bedded in). Treat it gently, brake sooner, until bedded in. Perhaps too, the pad material is a different brand inferior to the previous set.

Comment: make sure you didnt pig tail the caliper hose when you put it on.  it could be restricting the flow of the fluid

Answer (score 1):

This is fairly normal.  It will take some time for the pads and the rotors to wear a bit, and then braking performance will improve.  One thing you can do to accelerate that is to dismount the rotors and hit them with some 80 grit sandpaper.  Scratch them up good.  It will help your pads and rotors seat properly.